# Subsetting list of matrices with lapply

Tags: r

I would like to understand the following behavior. Let's say I have a list of matrices:

```
foo <- list(A = matrix(1:12, ncol = 3), B = matrix(1:16, ncol = 4))
foo

$A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    9
[2,]    2    6   10
[3,]    3    7   11
[4,]    4    8   12

$B
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
[3,]    3    7   11   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16
```

I want to subset the rows in each matrix with the same indices (or perhaps reorder them). I thought about doing the following, which doesn't give the desired result:

```
lapply(foo, "[", i = 1:2)
$A
[1] 1 2

$B
[1] 1 2
```

I tried also the following which gives the result as expected:

```
lapply(foo, "[", i = 1:2, exact = TRUE)
$A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    9
[2,]    2    6   10

$B
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
```

This suggests that `exact` was **FALSE** by default. But the documentation says it's **TRUE**. Indeed doing the following gives wrong (but different!) result:

```
lapply(foo, "[", i = 1:2, exact = FALSE)
$A
    
[1,]
[2,]

$B
    
[1,]
[2,]
```

This is confusing. Also `exact` is supposed to be an argument for `[[` not `[`. I have no idea what am I missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `?Extract`

> exact - Controls possible partial matching of [[ when extracting by a character vector (for most objects, but see under ‘Environments’). The default is no partial matching. Value NA allows partial matching but issues a warning when it occurs. Value FALSE allows partial matching without any warning.

and by default, it is `TRUE`

> x[[i, exact = TRUE]]

---

But, the argument `exact` with `i` are the only one available with `[[`, whereas with `[`, there are more arguments

> x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]

As we use `[` for extracting, it needs both `i` and `j` or a `,` in between.  Otherwise, without a `,`, by default, it just selects the elements without considering the dimensions

```
lapply(foo, "[", i = 1:2)
#$A
#[1] 1 2

#$B
#[1] 1 2
```

is equivalent to

```
foo[[1]][1:2]
#[1] 1 2
```

It can be more obvious if we increase the index

```
lapply(foo, "[", i = 1:7)
#$A
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

#$B
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

foo[[1]][1:7]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

In general, a `matrix` is just a `vector` with some `dim` attributes.  if we understand that cardinal rule, then it is more obvious.  With a `vector` there are no `i` or `j`, it is just a single index and that is what it is happening.  By specifying a `,`, we are specifying that it is row index it is extracting

Comment: I see what I missed now. To subset a matrix by row we do `x[1:2, ]`. If we do `x[1:2]` we do a different thing. So we need to be consistent. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use an anonymous function to make the operation clear that you want to apply :

```
lapply(foo, function(x) x[1:2, ])

#$A
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    5    9
#[2,]    2    6   10

#$B
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    5    9   13
#[2,]    2    6   10   14
```

Without using an anonymous function you can add an extra comma to indicate that you want to subset rows.

```
lapply(foo, "[", 1:2, )
```

Comment: Thanks. I was indeed using an anonymous function as an alternative. Sorry didn't mention in my post. The option of leaving an extra comma made me a lot more confused until I saw @akrun's response.